# node js - throw new Error('Can't set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js

I got error like the title.
Below is my code. Please could you anybody give me  advice?

I think I sent only one time per 'app.get'
I'd like to divide case for index.html and splash.html.
Before give response, I'd like make a delay for 1 second.

```js
app.use(delay(1000));
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    var pathName = req.url;
    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!');
    console.log(pathName);

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html', function(error, data) {
        console.log(__dirname);
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("load html");
            console.log(req.url);
            csp.add(req, res, options);
            res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
            res.end();
        }
    });    
});


app.get('/splash.html', function(req, res) {
    var pathName = req.url;
    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!');
    console.log(pathName);


    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/splash.html', function(error, data) {
        console.log(__dirname);
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("load html");
            console.log(req.url);
            csp.add(req, res, options);
            res.render(__dirname + '/views/splash.html');
            res.end();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: when you remove `app.use(delay(1000))` do you still get the same error?

Comment: no, i didn't get error without 'delay'. but i'd like to give delay using by express-delay. do you think that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `res.end()` after the `res.render` as `render` will end the response. If you want to set any headers, do so before.

Also the best way to achieve a delay is probably using a [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) before sending the response.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by using `rx` module, please see the code down below. The response is sent 3 seconds later, this is the module that I use for delays.

```
var app = require('express')();
const timeout = require('connect-timeout');
const Rx = require('rx');

// Response will be delayed for 3 seconds
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.onNext({
      response: 'potato'
    })
    observer.onCompleted()
  })
    .delay(new Date(Date.now() + 3000))    //setting it to 3 seconds
    .subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(x);                   //logs response: 'patato'
      console.log('this runs');
      res.status(200).send("3 seconds");
    }, (e) => {
      console.log('this does not');
    })
  });

app.listen(4000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply:) I could try this and have no issue!